# How do I help a dog with a swollen paw

Tags: dogs, injury

Our elderly terrier has a swollen back foot - one of his pads seems to be the issue and he has trouble walking. We've been keeping it clean and dry and trying to help him on rougher ground where possible.

What should we be doing - would putting booties on him help or be a problem? considering its foot pads, should we be bandaging it? Is there anything we should be doing in the short term that can help with the swelling?

Comment: Are there any more symptoms than swelling? Is there an actual wound or something? Does the swelling reoccur or is it the first time?

Comment: No actual wound, though the nail connected to that pad broke ages ago, and its a bit misshapen and he had swelling on the foot... 6 years ago.

Comment: Hmm, a broken nail should grow back shaped normally, but otherwise it doesn't sound suspicious. A visit to the vet might be in order.

Comment: If the vet says it is okay, there are some products that you can put on paw pads to help toughen them up / heal them.

Answer (score -2):

A swollen paw can be an indication of an allergic reaction. Check out this site for more information on symptoms and (other) possible causes: 
[Inflamation of the Paws in Dogs](https://wagwalking.com/condition/inflammation-of-the-paws)

Comment: to improve this answer please put some of the details from the site into your answer,like what to look for and the symptoms mentioned in the article.